# Recommendation for power cord replacement plugs

Tags: electrical, repair, cord-and-plug

Can anyone recommend a good quality brand of replacement plugs for power cords?

I've used them for...

- power tools
- equipment (120 and 240)
- extension cords (up to 50 amp)
- etc.

...and the ones they sell at local stores are just cheap!

Not inexpensive, cheap! :-)

I've had issues with everything from the housings breaking and screws stripping or loosening to problems with the strain relief.

So any recommendations would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Product recs are off-topic here, but I would check with a local electrical supply house if you want something better than big-box-grade....

Comment: Where should this post be?

Comment: Not on a Stack....like I said, an actual electrical supply house could give you better help with your plug woes than any hardware or big-box store...

Comment: What kind you got? I have a 10yo one on a 20yo hammer drill that's seen no end of abuse. [lowes.com/pd/Hubbell-15-Amp-125-Volt-Yellow-3-wire-Grounding-Plug](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hubbell-15-Amp-125-Volt-Yellow-3-wire-Grounding-Plug/3739251)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mazura, lots of different tools, new and old, i have a Milwaukee hammer that has at least 20 years of work on it that still kicks like new. In addition, I like to keep equipment service overhead and mobile in my shop so I have to customize quite a bit. I like to save money too (but keep safe) that's why I am looking for other options than my local supply house

Answer (score 1):

A proper electrical supply house is the best we can advise.   Retail shops with well lighted parking lots, exciting products on the endcaps, and candy at the  counter tend to also buy the cheapest products they can possibly get that won't be  returned at excessive rates.  And who returns a $7 plug?

You initially shop there for the bargain prices until it becomes habit, but those bargain prices don't come from buying in bulk the way the mythology says.  They come from going overseas and buying products that barely clear safety codes and are not factored for usability.